# pandas stacking a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, that Looks like:

```
sensorId                   1      2      3   

9b:f3:55:19:00:4b:12:00    1      7      8    
bf:f3:55:19:00:4b:12:00    6      5      9   
da:f3:55:19:00:4b:12:00    1      1      2
```

and I want to restructure into a dataframe with the following struture:

```
 sensorId                 y
 9b:f3:55:19:00:4b:12:00  1
 9b:f3:55:19:00:4b:12:00  7
 9b:f3:55:19:00:4b:12:00  8
 bf:f3:55:19:00:4b:12:00  6
 bf:f3:55:19:00:4b:12:00  5
 bf:f3:55:19:00:4b:12:00  9
 da:f3:55:19:00:4b:12:00  1
 da:f3:55:19:00:4b:12:00  1
 da:f3:55:19:00:4b:12:00  2
```

I tried using df.stack(), but the result isn't promising, because it Returns a pd.series:

```
9b:f3:55:19:00:4b:12:00  1      1
                         2      7
                         3      8
bf:f3:55:19:00:4b:12:00  1      6
                         2      5
                         3      9
da:f3:55:19:00:4b:12:00  1      1
                         2      1
                         3      2
```

Comment: Yes, it was. I accepted the answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use double [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) - first for remove second level of `MultiIndex` and second for convert `Series` to `DataFrame`:

```
df = df.stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index(name='y')
print (df)
                  sensorId  y
0  9b:f3:55:19:00:4b:12:00  1
1  9b:f3:55:19:00:4b:12:00  7
2  9b:f3:55:19:00:4b:12:00  8
3  bf:f3:55:19:00:4b:12:00  6
4  bf:f3:55:19:00:4b:12:00  5
5  bf:f3:55:19:00:4b:12:00  9
6  da:f3:55:19:00:4b:12:00  1
7  da:f3:55:19:00:4b:12:00  1
8  da:f3:55:19:00:4b:12:00  2
```

EDIT:

Because `df.stack` return `MultiIndex`, it means `sensorId` is not column, but index.

If `sensorId` is column:

```
df = df.set_index('sensorId').stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index(name='y')
```

Comment: Wait, i think you meant: `df = df.set_index('sensorId').stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index(name='y')`

Comment: Lol, jezrael, on your profile email code you could use `.map(...)` instead of `.apply(...)`

Comment: @U9-Forward - Thank you for suggestion :)

Comment: @jezrael Lol, it's nothing :-) :P

Answer (score 0):

Or use:

```
df = df.set_index('sensorId').stack().reset_index(name='y').drop('level_1',1)
```

And also a little correction to @jezrael's (his is nice tho):

```
df = df.set_index('sensorId').stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index(name='y')
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Is:

```
                  sensorId  y
0  9b:f3:55:19:00:4b:12:00  1
1  9b:f3:55:19:00:4b:12:00  7
2  9b:f3:55:19:00:4b:12:00  8
3  bf:f3:55:19:00:4b:12:00  6
4  bf:f3:55:19:00:4b:12:00  5
5  bf:f3:55:19:00:4b:12:00  9
6  da:f3:55:19:00:4b:12:00  1
7  da:f3:55:19:00:4b:12:00  1
8  da:f3:55:19:00:4b:12:00  2
```